# android exendable list on screen's foreground

Tags: android, listview

:D

I got a exependable ListView on the top of my layout, controlled by a fragment and below it an imageView.

What i want : when i expend my List, the image don't move but it goes in background

What happen : the image go down as much as the List expends.

I tryed to use Linear Layout with weight param. but i get the same results

Any idea?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:fillViewport="false"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/playlistFragement"
        android:name="com.example.pierr.puremusictest2.PlaylistFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        tools:layout="@layout/playlist_fragment" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mp3Image"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ii"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_margin="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/musicPlayerFragement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:name="com.example.pierr.puremusictest2.MusicPlayerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/menu_principal_fragment"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want this layout to fill the whole screen?

Comment: my layout already fill the whole screen.
my goal here is that my first fragment "playlistFragment" don't push down all the other view.